# New Registered Menu Not Displaying WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

- Registered the menu in functions.php
- Selected the menu in WordPress dashboard
- Added wp_nav_menu to the page

However it displays the **desktop-menu** not **sidebar-nav**.

I have no plugins running

**functions.php**

```
// Register Menus
register_nav_menus( array(
    'desktop-menu' => 'Desktop Menu',
    'mobile-menu' => 'Mobile Menu',    
    'sidebar-nav' => 'Sidebar Nav'
) );
```

**WordPress Dashboard Menu Selected**
[image]

**page.php**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('sidebar-nav'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code it will work

```
wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'sidebar-nav', 'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) );
```